# Get vector of string between strings (Php)

Tags: php, regex, string

I have been trying for some hours to get the strings delimited by `"{i}"`  and `"{[i]}"` such as in  `{i}Esse{[i]}`, where `i` is an integer. Based on 
[get string between 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313075/get-string-between-two-strings). I have no idea what it is happening so I decided asking for help.

My code is this:

```
<?php
include "keepGetInBetweenStrings.php";

$x['city1']='Esse';
$x['city2']='';
$x['city3']='é';
$x['city4']='um bom exemplo de';
$x['city5']=' uma portuguese-string!!';

$allCities='';
$cont=0;

for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    if($x['city'."$i"]!=''){
        $cont=$cont+1;
       $allCities=$allCities.'{'."$cont".'}'.$x['city'."$i"].'{['."$cont".']}'; 
    }
}
       echo $allCities;

       echo "<br>";


for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    $token=getInbetweenStrings('{'."$i".'}', '{['."$i".']}', $allCities);

    echo $token."<br>";
}       


?>

<?php

function getInBetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
    echo $start."<br>";
    echo $end."<br>";
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start(.*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
?>
```

I realy appreciate any help.

The output is

```
 {1}Esse{[1]}{2}é{[2]}{3}um bom exemplo de{[3]}{4} uma portuguese-string!!{[4]}

{1}
{[1]}

{2}
{[2]}

{3}
{[3]}

{4}
{[4]}

{5}
{[5]}
```

The pHP log error is

> [Mon Jan 27 19:08:20.406027 2014] [:error] [pid 2638] [client 127.0.0.1:50728] PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 2 in /var/www/NetBeansProjects/NewPhpProject/keepGetInBetweenStrings.php on line 8
>   [Mon Jan 27 19:08:20.406039 2014] [:error] [pid 2638] [client 127.0.0.1:50728] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/NetBeansProjects/NewPhpProject/keepGetInBetweenStrings.php on line 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `{x}` (where x is an integer) is a repetition operator in regexes. E.g.

```
/foo{7}/
```

will match

```
foooooooo
  1234567
```

`f`, an `o`, followed by 7 more `o`'s (`o{7}`).

In other words, you're literally inserting regex metacharacters into a regex, but don't want them treated as a regex - which means you're suffering from the regex equivalent of an SQL injection attack.

You need to `preg_quote` your values first, which escape those metacharacters, and give you something more like

```
/foo\{7\}/ instead.
```

So...

```
function getInBetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
     $regex = '/' . preg_quote($start) . '(.*)' . preg_quote($end) . '/';
     etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{...}` has special meaning in regular expressions. The `getInbetweenStrings` function that you copied from the other question assumes that the delimter strings will not include any special regexp characters. You need to use `preg_quote` to escape the characters to fix this.